# Unable to connect to SQL Server on AWS

Tags: sql-server

We have two Sql database servers (windows 2008 datacenter r2) with same name but with different IP. can it be possible?

we are not able to connect second one which we have created after. Both are on amazon aws

I have checked log and found this error .

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).`

the Ip of second server is private . we have set remote settings.Ports are also opened in the firewal. We are able to ping to the server but cannot connect the databases

Comment: Do you ping by the name or the IP?

Comment: I had pinged by IP

Comment: And can you try to connect to the DB by IP, too?  This sounds like a name resolution issue...

Comment: I have tried with IP  but getting this error  `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).`

Comment: Can you telnet to the servers on port 1433?